# How to plot a graph using jfreechart when data is coming continously

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I want to plot a line graph wherein data comes dynamically. Lets say for every second i have a new set of values that are to be plotted within the existing graph containing previous values. Time series graph offers such mechanism, but it need to have time as one of the parameter. But, time is not a variable for my case. How to keep updating this line graph with continuous incoming data.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the apparent contradiction between _every second_ and _time is not a variable_? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows representative data and your chosen chart type.

Answer (score 1):

You could

1. Pass an incremented value for each new data point. Alternatively you could take a look at source code of DynamicTimeSeriesCollection to see how they make it dynamic. Which leads to:
2. It seems that if you create your own data type that extends `org.jfree.data.general.Series` class then on any change you'd be able to call `fireSeriesChanged` which will trigger update of the graph.
3. As I read library I see more options. Did you try `XYSeries`, it has method called add(), I checked the source it call to this method triggers notification of change listeners. So using this class should be enough for your case.

Comment: its fine that i will add new data to XY series using add() method. But my doubt is whether we need to add the XY series to XYseries collection everytime whenever we modify data in XY series. If we do so , it throws an error saying that a XY series already exists with given name. So what should be done to keep on adding data to XY series and then update existing XY series in XY seriescollection.

Comment: @chaitu I don't think that you need to add `XYSeries` to `XYSeriesCollection`. Any change to `XYSeries` should be propagated using [Obeserver](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) mechanism.